# MySQL get Quarter (QTD) 1,2,3,4 for current year

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I was wondering if I could make a query with an result with Quarter 1,2,3 and 4.
for the current year (2017 for now) like this for example:

```
╔═══════════╦════════╗════════╗════════╗
║     Q1    ║   Q2   ║   Q3   ║   Q4   ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣════════║════════║
║   € K54   ║ € K14  ║ € K0   ║  € K0  ║
╚═══════════╩════════╝════════╝════════╝
```

And this is what I made for now:(the Q1 in this query is current so it changes to Q2 when it is Q2. And I dont want that i want to show them seperate like above example.)

```
╔══════════════╦
║     Q1       ║
╠══════════════╬
║   € K54      ║
╚══════════════╩
```

And this is the query i made. If there is no result found it will show € K0 automatically.

```
SELECT IF(SUM(totalExcl) IS NULL,0,
          CONCAT('€ K',
                FORMAT((SUM(totalExcl) / 1000),
                    0,'nl_NL'))) AS Q1
FROM
    ex.ps_order o LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_oxo_quotation q ON o.id_order = q.idOrder LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_employee e ON q.idEmployee = e.id_employee
WHERE
    QUARTER(q.date_add) = QUARTER(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
       AND e.lastname IN ('Ver')
```

I know how to make a previous Quarter query and current quarter query. But not exactly like Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 in current year.

---

I'm almost satisfied
I'm getting this as result right now:

```
╔═════════╦════════╗════════╗════════╗
║    Q1   ║   Q2   ║   Q3   ║   Q4   ║
╠═════════╬════════╣════════║════════║
║€96086,03║ € 0,00 ║ € 0,00 ║ € 0,00 ║
╚═════════╩════════╝════════╝════════╝
```

With this query:(thanks to [Bennjoe Mordeno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5760481/bennjoe-mordeno))

```
     SELECT 
 CONCAT('€ ',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 1 THEN totalExcl ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(100)), 2, 'nl_NL')) as Q1,
 CONCAT('€ ',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 2 THEN totalExcl ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(100)), 2, 'nl_NL')) as Q2,
 CONCAT('€ ',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 3 THEN totalExcl ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(100)), 2, 'nl_NL')) as Q3,
 CONCAT('€ ',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 4 THEN totalExcl ELSE 0 END) as CHAR(100)), 2, 'nl_NL')) as Q4
     FROM
```

To get it formatted use this one:

```
 SELECT 
 CONCAT('€ K',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 1 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END)/1000 AS CHAR(100)), 0, 'nl_NL')) as Q1,
 CONCAT('€ K',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 2 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END)/1000 AS CHAR(100)), 0, 'nl_NL')) as Q2,
 CONCAT('€ K',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 3 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END)/1000 AS CHAR(100)), 0, 'nl_NL')) as Q3,
 CONCAT('€ K',FORMAT(+ CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 4 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END)/1000 AS CHAR(100)), 0, 'nl_NL')) as Q4
 FROM
```

result:

```
╔═════════╦════════╗════════╗════════╗
║    Q1   ║   Q2   ║   Q3   ║   Q4   ║
╠═════════╬════════╣════════║════════║
║ € K96   ║  € 0   ║  € 0   ║  € 0   ║
╚═════════╩════════╝════════╝════════╝
```

Comment: Love the unicode art

Comment: You can just remove the string 'K' on the Q2 Q3 Q4 column for the query. What it does it just concatenates '€ K' (which you'll change to '€ ')along with the computed sum(converted to string), so to remove the K, simply remove the K before concatenating them.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you wanted it to be formatted. If it's to just divide it by 1000, then just change it to this. CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 1 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END)/1000 AS CHAR(100)) as Q1

Comment: Thanks mate both workt fine formatted and vice versa.

Comment: Glad to help! @Deniz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case when

```
 SELECT 
 '€ K' + CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add)= 1 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(100)) as Q1,
 '€ K' + CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add) = 2 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(100)) as Q2,
 '€ K' + CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add)= 3 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(100)) as Q3,
 '€ K' + CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(q.date_add)= 4 THEN totalexcl ELSE 0 END) as VARCHAR(100)) as Q4
 FROM
  ex.ps_order o LEFT JOIN
  ex.ps_oxo_quotation q ON o.id_order = q.idOrder LEFT JOIN
  ex.ps_employee e ON q.idEmployee = e.id_employee
  WHERE e.lastname IN ('Ver')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(100)) as Q1,  '€ K' + CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 2 THEN totalexcl EL' at line 2  (syntax error: unexpected 'VARCHAR' (varchar))

Comment: I fixed that changed VARCHAR to CHAR but now i'm getting this one Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Quarter' in 'field list'

Comment: Please try replacing Quarter with QUARTER(q.date_add) @Deniz